# MSAL / ASP.NET Core - How to check token cache contents?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-web

In my ASP.Net Core Mvc confidential web app I am using Microsoft Identity Web / Platform with AAD which I would like to call a downstream WebAPI. The web app Startup.cs is as follows:

```
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { Configuration["ConfigSection:ConfigSectionScopes"] })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

When a user signs in, if I understood correctly their access token (acquired at sign-in, auth code flow requesting access token too) is stored in the InMemoryTokenCache.

From an MVC Controller, how do I access the token cache for the signed in user? I can acquire a token via `ITokenAcquisition` and `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` (providing scopes) successfully, but I would like to check the cache to determine if the token is there and if other tokens are present for the user. I tried `var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();` but this is always null.

Answer (score 0):

[`AddInMemoryTokenCaches`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/9bdf816d2f0e8fd029328ad11cf33217da963ba9/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/TokenCacheProviders/InMemory/InMemoryTokenCacheProviderExtension.cs#L17) registers `IMsalTokenCacheProvider` and `IMemoryCache` to the IOC container.

In your controller you can easily pick both up like so:

```cs
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMsalTokenCacheProvider _cacheProvider;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public WeatherForecastController(IMsalTokenCacheProvider cacheProvider, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
        _cache = cache;
    }
    ...
}
```

Looking at the two, it seems you can't extract much value from `IMsalTokenCacheProvider` so I'd suggest to stick with the `IMemoryCache` instance